# How to customise dialog message to prompt user for opening setting page

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, user-permissions, runtime-permissions

My attempt :
`1. Its a OS generated dialog  for open setting page`

`2. Didn't find any String to modify this info.plist file` 
 P.S - Already  have this key  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
 This app requires your location so that we can centre the map on you & show you where the project is  
but I think it uses "UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString"

`3. Using "permission_handler" plugin` 
Please help me to modify this message dialog in flutter

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before iOS 6 it was possible to set the purpose property on the CLLocationManager class but this has long been deprecated in favor of using the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription strings in the Info.plist.

As far as I am aware there is no other way to replace this message. See original documentation

[Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423742-purpose)